# We throwing $m$ balls to $n$ cells....

Tags: probability, expectation, balls-in-bins

We throwing $m$ balls to $n$ cells randomly...
At each cell can be more then one ball, or (of course) it can still empty.

What is the expectation of the **empty** cells?

I'd like to get any help!

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with exception?

Comment: Expectation... Sorry! @MusséRedi My mistake!

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I actually don't know where to start. $X$ is for the balls or for the cells?

Comment: What you mean with the *expectation value of the empty cells* ? An expectation value is calculated by summing up the products of the actual values $x$ you get multiplied by the probability $P(x) $. What probabilty (distribution) have you found?

Comment: @MusséRedi, I think that Bananarama solve it, if I'm understant it right... Thank you!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using stars and bars there are $\binom{m+n-1}{n-1}$ ways to distribute the balls allowing for empty cells.

Again by stars and bars there are $\binom{n}{i}\binom{m+n-i-1}{n-i-1}$ ways to leave exactly $i$ cells empty. Since there are $\binom{n}{i}$ ways to select the empty cells and $\binom{m+n-i-1}{n-i-1}$ ways to divide $m$ balls in $n-i$ cells.

Thus the expected number of empty cells is:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{\binom{n}{i}\binom{m+n-i-1}{n-i-1}i}{\binom{m+n-1}{n-1}}$$

---

Two years later I realize this is wrong, as for example $(1,1)$ does not have the same probability as $(2,0)$. The answer by Mr.Spot is correct, and more easily computable.

Comment: What is "stars and bars"? Thank you!

Comment: How I get from here $E(X)$?

Comment: stars and bars is a method for counting what you want to count: here is a [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) E(X) is the final formula.

Answer (score 9):

The number of balls per cell has a multinomial distribution. But for any one cell, it is binomial. The probability a ball lands in that one cell is $1/n$ and outside it is $(1-1/n). $ The probability that that particular cell remains empty after all balls are thrown is $(1-1/n)^m. $ Now define the Indicator variable $I_k=1$ if cell number $k$ remains empty and $=0$ if cell $k$ is not empty. Then the expected number of empty cells is
$$E\sum_{k=1}^n I_k = \sum_{k=1}^nP(\text{cell k is empty})= n(1-1/n)^m   $$

Answer (score 1):

I see that this problem has been answered, but I thought I'd share my approach anyway.

I find it's most helpful to look at this problem from the perspective of a cell. "If I am a cell, what is the probability that I will remain empty after all $m$ balls are thrown?" Well, each time a ball is thrown, there is a $\frac{n-1}{n}$ chance that it will not land in me. So the probability that I remain empty after all the balls are thrown is $\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^m$, since this event must occur $m$ times. So now we have a formula for the probability that an individual cell will be empty after all of the balls are thrown; to get the expected number of empty cells, we simply multiply this probability by the number of cells, i.e. $n\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^m$.